# JSF + Spring MVC integration everything works but exception is thrown

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-mvc

I need help identifying the reason why an exception is being thrown and how to solve it.

I have integrated JSF into my Spring MVC project, and I've managed to get it to work just as i need to. But once I open JSF view, an exception is thrown but everything works just fine. here is the exception:

```
03.01.2011 21:49:07 com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler initialize
SEVERE: Compiler Initialization Error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\ (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.facelets.util.Classpath.getAlternativeJarFile(Classpath.java:214)
    at com.sun.facelets.util.Classpath.search(Classpath.java:71)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:428)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:87)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:104)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:218)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:149)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:100)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:517)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView.renderMergedOutputModel(JsfView.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What file is it looking for? Why? 
How can I provide more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not sure what application server you're using here, but after scanning the web for situation like yours, I see a recurring pattern: a bug is lurking somewhere in the facelets implementation and upgrading to a newer version of the library itself or app server should help.

Sources:

1. [BEA10](http://java.net/jira/browse/FACELETS-323)
2. [Seam framework bug report](http://seamframework.org/17674.lace)
3. [Bad file descriptor under Websphere](http://java.net/jira/browse/FACELETS-306)

They're pretty much the same or identical, but they do hint that there aren't bugs in your code.

Comment: oh sorry indeed i forgot to mention i am using tomcat 6
i will take a look on versions

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else is gonna have this problem i've found out what exactly was wrong. I was deploying my application as exploded war and this caused this error. after changing it to regular war or after deploying on remote server everything was ok.